# Implementing a composite index

Tags: mysql

I've been reading about how a composite index can improve performance but am still a unclear on a few things.  I have an INNODB database that has over 20 million entries with 8 data points each.  Its performance has dropped substantially in the past few months.  The server has 6 cores with 4gb mem which will be increased soon, but there's no indication on the server that I'm running low on mem.  INNODB settings have been changed in my.cnf to;

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M
innodb_log_file_size = 147M
```

These settings have helped in the past.  So, my understanding is that many factors can contribute to the performance decrease, including the fact that I originally I had no indexing at all.  Indexing methods are predicated on the type of queries that are run.  So, this is my table;

```
cdr_records | CREATE TABLE `cdr_records` (
  `dateTimeOrigination` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `callingPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finalCalledPartyNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pkid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `destDeviceName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkid`),
  KEY `dateTimeOrigination` (`dateTimeOrigination`),
  KEY `callingPartyNumber` (`callingPartyNumber`),
  KEY `originalCalledPartyNumber` (`originalCalledPartyNumber`),
  KEY `finalCalledPartyNumber` (`finalCalledPartyNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

So, typically, a query will take a value and search callingPartyNumber, originalCalledPartyNumber, and finalCalledPartyNumber to find any entries related to it in the table.  So, it wouldn't make any sense to use individual indexes like I have illustrated above because I typically don't run queries like this.  However, I have another job in the evenings that is basically;

```
select * from cdr_records;
```

In this case, it sounds like it would be a good idea to have another composite index with all columns in it.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: IF you are retreving the whole table,i.e.,SELECT *,then no index will be helpful.Indexes are helpful when you get only a smallish portion of the data

Comment: Can you please explain "a query will take a value and search callingPartyNumber, originalCalledPartyNumber, and finalCalledPartyNumber to find any entries related to it in the table". What do you mean ? Are you doing a `SELECT callingPartyNumber, originalCalledPartyNumber, finalCalledPartyNumber FROM xxxx WHERE ....` or a `SELECT * FROM xx WHERE callingPartyNumber = xx AND/OR originalCalledPartyNumber = xx AND/OR finalCalledPartyNumber = xx` ?

Comment: @Val Bonn - "select * cdr_records where (callingPartyNumber = '12345') or (originalCalledPartyNumber = '12345') or (finalCalledPartyNumber = '12345');"

Comment: @Kimomaru for optimum performance on this criteria you should add single column indexes on all of these columns. `OR` is exclusive criteria, you can look at this as if it were 3 different queries.

Comment: @php_nub_qq - There may be a larger issue I'm missing.  Like I mentioned, adding the single column index has slowed the server down to the point where jobs can't be run (they're backing up at this point).  Wondering if adding mem and changing the innodb pool size is the right way to go.

Comment: @Kimomaru I am quite sure that adding indexes to these 3 columns will speed things up, there is not much you have shown, there might be some sorting or grouping that is causing the delay, you should try `EXPLAIN`ing your queries, look for "Using filesort" or "Using temporary".

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of the composite index comes when you need to select/sort/group based on multiple columns, in the same fashion.

I remember there was a very good example with a phone book analogy I read somewhere. As the names in a phone book are ordered alphabetically it is very easy for you to sort through them and find the one you need based on the letters of the name from left to right. You can imagine that is a composite index of the letters in the names.

If the names were ordered only by the first letter and subsequent letters were chaotic (single column index) you would have to go through all records after you find the first letter, which will take a lot of time.

With a composite index, you can start from left to right and very easily find the record you are looking for, this is also the reason why you can't use for example the second or third column of the composite index, because you need the previous ones in order for it to work. Imagine trying to find all names whose third letter is "a" in the phone book, it would be a nightmare, you would need a separate index just for that, which is exactly what you need to do if you need to use a column from a composite index without using other columns from the index before it.

Bear in mind that the phone book example assumes that each letter of the names is a separate column, that could be a little confusing.

The other great strength of the composite indexes are unique composite indexes, which allow you to apply higher logical restrictions on your data that is very handy when you need it. Has nothing to do with performance but I thought it was worth to mention.

In your question your sql has no criteria, so there will be no index used. It is always recommended to use `EXPLAIN` to see what is going on, you can never be sure!

Comment: Thank you.  I will remove the indexes I added as they seemed to have slowed the server down and run some queries with explain to get a better understanding.

Comment: @Kimomaru if you are looking to speed up a `SELECT * FROM table` query the only thing that will speed it up is adding a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: you can also post the result from the EXPLAIN to see whats wrong. Also the my.cnf, OS and Hardware like CPU,RAM, DISK size and max user/Connection you use to share the Memory in the my.cnf

Comment: @php_nub_qq - interesting.  So, it sounds like the idea would be to set a limit and pull at regular intervals.  Even if I remove the indexes (which I am doing right now), I still have the issue of slow performance.  Is this something that only fast hardware can address, maybe reducing the database size?  What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: @Kimomaru depending on what you need to do, if you actually need to get all of these millions of records, it makes no sense to use `LIMIT`, unless you're trying to break down the load on the machine. For getting all records I'm afraid there's not much you can do besides upgrading your hardware or caching.

Comment: @php_nub_qq - Yeah, I'm starting to see that.  Maybe six months would make more sense.  Would I use a stored proc to cut off anything over 6 months?  New territory for me.

Comment: @Kimomaru a limit dosent speed up your query if you use an **ORDER BY** in your Query, The LIMIT do the work after sorting the result and you only transfer not so much data to the client.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, its not a good idea to set a composite index over all fields.
Wich field you are put i one or more index depends on your Querys.

**Note:**
MySQL can only use **one** Index per Query and can use composite Index only if all fields from left site on are used.
You not may use all field.

**Example:**
 if you have an index x on the field **name, street, number** so this index will used when you query (in WHERE) 
name or 
name and street or 
name, street and numer 
**but not if you search only**
street or 
street an number.

To find out if your index working well with your query put **EXPLAIN** before your query and you can see wich indexe are used from your query.